# DataTable with Rows will not bind to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to build a simple page that will allow for bulk SQL Searches using a text area. The textbox is split on each new line and each line taken as a parameter to query. The resulting row is then added to a DataTable.

There isn't a problem with the query and the DataTable is built and returned as I expected when checked through debug mode. The only problem is when I attempt to bind the DataTable to the gridview , the gridview is left without rows.

I have been scratching my head at this for a hwile now and cannot figure out why the DataTable will not bind. The column names all match up but the actual table in result is unnamed. Is this an issue?

Here's the code.

ASPX:

```
    <asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" 
        runat="server"            
        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SIM NUMBER" HeaderText="SIM NUMBER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Voice" HeaderText="Voice" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IMSI" HeaderText="IMSI" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tariff" HeaderText="Tariff" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Contract Start" HeaderText="Contract Start" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier" HeaderText="Supplier" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the C# Code:

```
public partial class Query : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected static string numbers = "";
    protected static string number;
    protected static DataTable result = new DataTable();

    protected static string simNumber;
    protected static string voice;
    protected static string IMSI;
    protected static string tariff;
    protected static string contractStart;
    protected static string supplier;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Reset();
        result.Columns.Add("SIM NUMBER", typeof(string));
        result.Columns.Add("Voice", typeof(string));
        result.Columns.Add("IMSI", typeof(string));
        result.Columns.Add("Tariff", typeof(string));
        result.Columns.Add("Contract Start", typeof(string));
        result.Columns.Add("Supplier", typeof(string));
        numbers = TextArea1.Value.ToString();
        search();
        GridView1.DataSource = result;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected static void search()
    {
        string[] split = numbers.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string line in split)
        {
            if (line == string.Empty)
                continue;

            number = line;
            getSupplierInfo();
        }
    }

    protected static void getSupplierInfo()
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connections.supplierInfo()))
        {
            string sql = " SELECT * FROM UnionSuppliers WHERE SIM_NUMBER LIKE @parameter ";
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                CommandTimeout = 300,
                CommandText = sql,
                Connection = conn
            })
            {                    
                select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", number);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.SelectCommand = select;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                DT = ds.Tables[0];
            }

        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in DT.Rows)
        {
            simNumber = dr["SIM_NUMBER"].ToString();
            voice = dr["Voice"].ToString();
            IMSI = dr["IMSI"].ToString();
            tariff = dr["Tariff"].ToString();
            contractStart = dr["Contract_start"].ToString();
            supplier = dr["Supplier"].ToString();
            addRow();
        }
    }

    protected static void addRow()
    {
        DataRow simResult = result.NewRow();

        simResult["SIM Number"] = simNumber;
        simResult["Voice"] = voice;
        simResult["IMSI"] = IMSI;
        simResult["Tariff"] = tariff;
        simResult["Contract Start"] = contractStart;
        simResult["Supplier"] = supplier;
        result.Rows.Add(simResult);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm sure its something really simple that i'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use a static DataTable, that will create locks at the best.

Comment: Ok So Problem solved. It required a DataKey Name to be set. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```

to:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="true"
```

Comment: No Hasn't worked. I'm not sure thats the issue as I've set the column bindings manually.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can try like this in aspx file

```
<Columns>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Your_Field_Name") %>'></asp:Label> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</Columns>
```

and in cs file just fit below code

```
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connections.supplierInfo()))
    {
        string sql = " SELECT * FROM UnionSuppliers WHERE SIM_NUMBER LIKE @parameter ";
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            CommandTimeout = 300,
            CommandText = sql,
            Connection = conn
        })
        {                    
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", number);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.SelectCommand = select;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            DT = ds.Tables[0];
        }

    }
```

And now bind your Datatable to Grid View.

```
    GridView1.DataSource = DT;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```